# Getting a tilebase from mouse position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I have a grid component and for its children I have 3 layers of tilemaps. I'm trying to get the position of a tilebase from specific layer by using my mouse location.

```
        var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        var mousePosTranslated = groundLayer.WorldToCell(mousePos);`

        TileBase tile = groundLayer.GetTile(mousePosTranslated);

        Debug.Log(tile.GetType());
```

tried it without mousePosTranslated just Input.mouseposition but nevertheless I just get a null from GetTile. With the tilebase I get from GetTile I plan on using GetTileData to get its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your tilemap component holding objects transform and make sure their scale.z is 0 by making it 0.
Now you can interact with the tilemap by mouse.